# About compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

When seeing a proof of Fredholm's alternative I don't get the following:

Let $T$ be compact from a Banach space $X$ to itself, and $\lambda \neq 0$. Define $S=I-T$, $S^k$ its $k$-th power and $N_k=$ker$(S^k)$.

Is it true that $S(N_{k-1})=N_{k}$? One of the inclusions is clear, but the other one isn't, because $S$ is not necessarily onto (is it?). And in the proof it seems to me that we need that to happen.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `\ker` to produce $\ker$ (just like with `\sin` for $\sin$, `\log` for $\log$, etc.)

Comment: Do you mean $S=\lambda I-T$?

Comment: The only clear inclusion for me is $S(\mbox{Ker} S^k)\subseteq \mbox{Ker} S^{k-1}$. And that's true of any operator $S$. Also clear is $\mbox{Ker} S^{k-1}\subseteq \mbox{Ker} S^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the finite-dimensional case and for $k=2$ it is not necessarily true that $S(\ker S^k) = \ker S^{k-1}$: $\text{ran}(S) \cap \ker S^K$ might be $\{0\}$, e.g. for
$$ S = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr
                0 & 0\cr}$$